# openssl s_server without PSK/certificate, but with client certificate validation

Tags: openssl

Is it possible to use openSSL without encryption and without a certificate at the server, but with validation of the client certificate? 
I'm not sure which cipher allows this (or where to get this info).
I tried the following:

server:

```
openssl s_server -cipher NULL-SHA256 -nocert -CAfile client_cert.pem -Verify 4 -verify_return_error  -accept 44330 -www
```

client:

```
openssl s_client -cipher NULL-SHA256 -cert client_cert.pem -key client_key.pem  -connect 10.10.1.87:44330
```

But I'm getting errors at the server and at the client:

server error:

```
4699434604:error:140270C1:SSL routines:ACCEPT_SR_CLNT_HELLO_C:no shared cipher:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-47.11.1/libressl-2.8/ssl/ssl_srvr.c:1115:
ACCEPT
```

client error:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
4447727212:error:14004410:SSL routines:CONNECT_CR_SRVR_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-47.11.1/libressl-2.8/ssl/ssl_pkt.c:1200:SSL alert number 40
4447727212:error:140040E5:SSL routines:CONNECT_CR_SRVR_HELLO:ssl handshake failure:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-47.11.1/libressl-2.8/ssl/ssl_pkt.c:585:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 0 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID:
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key:
    Start Time: 1582732375
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

Answer (score 2):

From [RFC 5246 (TLS 1.2)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.4.4):

> A **non-anonymous server** can optionally request a certificate from
> the client, if appropriate for the selected cipher suite.

Thus, you need at least a cipher suite where the server is not anonymous, i.e. NULL as you've tried to use will not work.

Comment: NULL-SHA256 is (the OpenSSL name for) TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA256, which is not anonymous and would allow client auth, but requires an RSA key-and-cert which OP did not provide so it can't be negotiated, hence 'no shared cipher'. It is true however there is no ciphersuite (or pre-1.3 combined keyexchange) that allows client auth without server auth.

Comment: "It is true however there is no ciphersuite (or pre-1.3 combined keyexchange) that allows client auth without server auth" - Thanks, that answers my question.